# Change/hide ToolBar menu image

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have `Activity` with `ToolBar`. This activity has place for dynamically changing `Fragments`.

This `ToolBar` has menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_kiss"
        android:title="@string/action_kiss"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/lips_ic"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

So I want to hide (make gone) this menu item (icon) when I make transaction to one of my `Fragments`.

Found this in docs but it doesn't help at all:

```
mToolbar.getMenu().removeGroup(R.id.action_kiss);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to change visibility in menu items:

```
mToolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_kiss).setVisible(true/false);
```